# How do I preselect the service that will be chosen in a UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity, twitterkit

I am wondering how Dolly (iOS app) does this. If I select the Twitter icon in the first screenshot, the view in the second screen appears immediately.

[image]

[image]

That second screenshot is what is presented after you typically click the Twitter service from the scrollable list presented in a UIActivityViewController (below), e.g. Facebook, Mail, Messages, Twitter, etc. But, I never had to click Twitter from the below menu.

[image]

Again, the share sheet was presented immediately. I did not have to select Twitter from the built in set of options. So, I am wondering what, if anything I can do to duplicate this behavior. Possibly a few lines that I am missing below?

```
func handleTwitterShareButtonTapped(){
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController.init(activityItems: [ShareActivityItemStringSource(), ShareActivityItemURLSource()], applicationActivities: [])

    //preselect twitter from services somehow???

    navigationController?.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Or, perhaps there is some swizzling magic that I need to do. If this does involve swizzle magic, any resources that might get me going would be extremely helpful.

Thanks!!!

Comment: did you find a solution please?